# Spark scala not able to push data in Hive table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I am try to push data in existing hive table, i  have already created orc table in hive not able to push data in hive. this code is work if i copy paste on spark console but not able to run by spark-submit.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
 import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
 object TestCode {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("first example").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    for (i <- 0 to 100 - 1) {
    //  sample value but it replace with business logic. and try to push into table.for loop consider as business logic.
      var fstring = "fstring" + i
      var cmd = "cmd" + i
      var idpath = "idpath" + i
      import sqlContext.implicits._
      val sDF = Seq((fstring, cmd, idpath)).toDF("t_als_s_path", "t_als_s_cmd", "t_als_s_pd")
      sDF.write.insertInto("l_sequence");
      //sDF.write.format("orc").saveAsTable("l_sequence");
      println("write data ==> " + i)
    }
   }
```

Giving the error.

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: l_sequence;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:449)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:455)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:453)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:453)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:443)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCachedData$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCachedData(QueryExecution.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto(DataFrameWriter.scala:259)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
        at com.hq.bds.Helloword$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Helloword.scala:16)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
        at com.hq.bds.Helloword$.main(Helloword.scala:10)
        at com.hq.bds.Helloword.main(Helloword.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: Are you running on clouder VM or on cluster.. what is the cluster size that you are working on. Can you add your spark-submit command

Comment: If you are working in a local environment with client-mode you usually need to send the hive.xml file through the --files option to the spark-submit. For instance in a docker installation i send:

--files '/etc/spark/conf.dist/hive-site.xml'

Comment: Thanks for quick response. i have setup of hortonworks 2.4 cluster setup of 5 machine. and spark-submit command is 
/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/bin/spark-submit --class com.qh.bds.Helloword /root/users/pushdata_poc.jar

Comment: can you guide me how to do it..

Answer (score 0):

You need to link hive-site.xml with spark conf or copy hive-site.xml into spark conf directory. Spark is not 
able to find your hive metastore (derby database which is by default), so for that we have to link hive-conf to spark conf direcrtory.

Finally, to connect Spark SQL to an existing Hive installation, you must copy your hive-site.xml file to Spark’s configuration directory ($SPARK_HOME/conf). If you
don’t have an existing Hive installation, Spark SQL will still run.

Sudo to root user and then copy hive-site to spark conf directory.

```
sudo -u root 
cp /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml /etc/spark/conf
```

Comment: Try giving {DB_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME} in your sql query.. hope that should work

Comment: Are you sure that table exists in your hive db, can you run val df = sqlContext.table("db_name.table_name") and see if it works fine

Comment: No, can you please run the above command and check, i wanted to check  spark connectivity with your hive metastore

Comment: i have update in code and re run it give me error.. 
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchDatabaseException: Database 'bds_db' not found;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168716/discussion-between-big-data-hadoop-dev-and-salmanbw).